# pre-push git hook?

Tags: git, githooks

I would like to run a compression script before `git push` such that anytime a user tries to push changes to a remote repository, it checks for uncommitted changes in the compressible assets, aborts `git push`, runs `git commit`, then runs `git push` again.

Is something like that possible using only git hooks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this patch](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/8/19/2996404).

See `.git/hooks/` in your repo for sample hooks, maybe you will see some alternative.

Comment: That link is now dead.

Answer (score 5):

Git is getting a `pre-push` hook in the `1.8.2` release.

Sample `pre-push` script: https://github.com/git/git/blob/87c86dd14abe8db7d00b0df5661ef8cf147a72a3/templates/hooks--pre-push.sample

1.8.2 draft release notes talking about the new pre-push hook: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt

Comment: But does that allow doing commits? The OP asked for a way to do commits and then restart the push; how to do that?