# Not doing git CRLF conversion for .m matlab files?

Tags: git, matlab, core.autocrlf

Matlab .m files use the Unix LF line endings even on Windows. I'm look to set up the git config file so that the .m files are *not* converted back to CRLF as other regular text files would be (i.e. I am using LF as the default style within the repo, even though its Windows).

Can this be done?

EDIT: from Matlab 2008b manual. (under Editing and Debugging M-Files)

> Line Endings Removed in Files Provided with MATLAB Software for
>   Windows Platforms; Impacts Viewing in Notepad Application
>
> In previous versions, text files provided with MATLAB for Windows
>   platforms included a carriage return and line feed at the end of each
>   line. Starting in R2007b, the text files MATLAB provides do not
>   include a carriage return and line feed at the end of each line.
>
> File types affected are:
>         .asc
>         .bat
>         .c
>         .cc
>         .cdr
>         .cpp
>         .def
>         .for
>         gs.rights
>         .h
>         .ini
>         .m
>         .mdl
>         .pl
>         readme
>         .tlc
>         .tmf
>         .txt
>
> There is no impact if you view the files in MATLAB and other common
>   text editors, with the known exception of the Microsoft Notepad
>   application.
>
> Compatibility Considerations.   If you use the Notepad application to
>   view files provided with MATLAB, you see carriage return and line feed
>   symbols instead of line endings. This makes the files less readable in
>   the Notepad application. Other text editors might display the symbols
>   instead of line endings, but of the common text editors tested, none
>   have been found that do so.
>
> As an alternative to the Notepad application, use the Microsoft
>   WordPad application, provided with Windows platforms, or another text
>   editor to view the files.

Comment: BTW are you sure of that first statement? On my Windows machine, MATLAB creates files with CRLF line endings by default...

Comment: @Amro: on my machine it is, but I'll ask around to see if there is a 'hidden' Matlab setting for it.

Comment: Added extract from Matlab help file on LF normalisation on Windows.

Comment: Despite the claimed LF normalization, R2012a on Windows 7 is writing out CRLF newline sequences, at least for newly created files.

Comment: @ChristopherBarber: I'll have to look out for that and see if it is W7 that's doing it or R2012a (I should be able to check R2012a on XP).

Answer (score 3):

Set the `core.autocrlf` config to false and `core.eol` to `lf` on Windows.

```
[core]
    autocrlf = false
    eol = lf
```

Also, have a look at [`gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) under `Checking-out and checking-in`

Comment: so in gitattributes I'll need `*.m eol=lf` then ? (same as the *.sh example in the man page)

Comment: @Philip Oakley - Yes, you can have `*.m eol=lf` in `.gitattributes`

Comment: :@manojlds: Isn't it 'autocrlf = true' for general windows text files being normalised to LF in the repo, and then checked out as CRLF in the working directory? [The .gitattributes file catching the matlab files as being different on check out]

Comment: I also forgot `safecrlf=true` which I need to try with this mixed file type scenario.

Comment: I tried the `safecrlf=true` with mixed results. Initially I'm building a history of old work. For those files I needed it off (I commented it out with a #) as some of the files weren't normalised (i.e. I had mixed CR and CRLF between files so wouldn't check in and check out unchanged; but I do want to normalize them!). Once I've done the hisrory the current files should already conform so I should be able to re-instate `safecrlf=true`

Answer (score 0):

Change autocrlf to false. set core.whitespace to cr-at-eol (This will ensure you don't get ^M highlighted as problematic whitespace in diffs and patches). Use vim or another editor to ensure you have lfs in your .m files.